# Clean way to go from IEnumerable<T?> to IEnumerable<T> in a project with nullable reference types enabled

Tags: c#, linq

When processing the elements of a JsonArray with linq, the signature is `IEnumerable<JsonNode?>`. So I was trying to come up with a clean filter that would only select the non-null elements. `.Where(x => x!=null)` does not work because the signature is still `IEnumerable<JsonNode?>` after that (resulting in warnings).

The following extension method *does* work, but is there a less clunky way to achieve the same?

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> NotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> seq) where T : class 
    {
        foreach(var v in seq)
        {
            if(v != null) yield return v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work, but how about `.Where(x => x.HasValue).Select(x => x.Value)`?

Comment: @RonBeyer it surely won't cause `where T : class`

Comment: @RonBeyer unfortunately nullable refs don't have those properties

Comment: Try using `Where(i => i != null)!` (i.e. end with null forgiving operator)

Comment: @GuruStron tried it, the output signature is still `IEnumerable<JsonNode?>` after that

Comment: @GuruStron But that was a good tip.. this works: `.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x!)`

Comment: @jmik I meant to use it in your extension method. Your solution supposed to be my next "inline" suggestion)